# Difference between php 4 and php 5?

Tags: php, migration, php4

I'm in search of the web hosting space, and got to know the PHP version is 4.3 and MySQL Version 4.1

But i developed my application in MySQL version 5.x and PHP version 5.x

Can anyone give me the differences in versions ?

what all i cannot access now ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 8):

PHP version 5 I look at as when PHP became a real language, for a whole bunch of reasons, but most importantly because it became possible to write respectable Object Oriented code.

But don't deemphasize the difference between MySQL 4 and 5 - I think it's even deeper and more significant. MySQl 5 was when MySQL became a real relational database platform, for a whole bunch of reasons, but most importantly because it became possible to write fully expressive SQL statements (starting with full subquery support).

Just those two limitations on the earlier versions are, I hope, showstoppers for you. There's no reasonable excuse for accepting less than version 5 of either.

Comment: Wordpress still works on PHP4, and that's an excellent platform.

Comment: It's a great platform and I'm intimately familiar with it. I wish it were more object-oriented all the time. I keep threatening to encapsulate the whole thing in classes (posts, pages, links, categories, authors, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Why not take a look at the PHP docs:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.migration5.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php

With regards to MySQL you can track changes in versions here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/key-changes.html

Major new features added to MySQL 5.0 and 5.1 that may not work/won't work in 4.x can be located here:

MySQL 5.0 - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html

MySQL 5.1 - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-nutshell.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [basic overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history) of the release history.  PHP 5 was a big change.

I won't go into huge detail on the differences though since [PHP 4 is deprecated](http://www.wolerized.com/blog/remi-woler/php4-deprecated).  Stick with PHP 5 & MySQL 5.  I'd be surprised if a webhost didn't offer PHP 5 as well as 4.  4 should only be used with legacy code and should never be used for new development.